# What is the highest damage weapon usable by a Soul Level 1 Pyromancer?

Tags: dark-souls

I'm currently working my way through a Soul Level 1 playthrough of Dark Souls. I'm using the Pyromancer class, since that is the only class that starts at SL1.

Because I'm not leveling my character, I'm stuck with the base stats of the Pyromancer. This limits the weapons I'm able to equip and use effectively.

My current weapon of choice is the Raw Reinforced Club. Are there any weapons, regular or rare, with a higher damage than a Raw Reinforced Club?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing my SL1 run right now and for me raw damage output per blow is definitely not all that matters.

I prefer to have a weapon with a nice move set and I've upgraded two hand axes with lightning and fire for quite decent damage (400 total for +5 lightning) and really fast blows with low stamina drainage ( = around five blows in quick succession).

But sure, for maximum damage the reinforced club is the way to go as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

I think both Lightning Reinforced Club and Fire Reinforced Club would both be more effective than a Raw one on a lvl 1 character. Other than that, assuming you don't want to kill off blacksmiths, I'd go with Lightning Reinforced Club. Battle Axe is a relatively good option too. Also, I keep a Morning Star handy just for the bleed damage. Makes killing certain enemies a lot easier.

Comment: Here's a link to pretty much everything done on a lvl1 pyromancer. Mimicing all he does makes things very easy, so watch only if you don't mind having a lot of "spoilers". Doesn't include the DLC content. http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/51620/t1797567-soul-level-1-pyromancer-playthrough/

Comment: Agreed that lightning/fire > raw. However, it depends on where you're up to in the game. At the time of writing, I hadn't yet reached Anor Londo, nor explored The Catacombs. Raw is hard to beat under these circumstances.

Comment: +1 because, although I accepted the other answer, yours is good too.

Answer (score 1):

Before going to Anor Londo. You can get a Magic+5 reinforced club, hand axe, battle axe, mace or morning star by farming green titanite shards from the goo enemies outside the bonfire on the way down to the gaping dragon. You can also get blue titanite chunks from the black knight at the bottom of darkroot basin and the crystal golems near the hydra, easiest to get to past Havel. So you could even get a Mag+9 whatever with some grinding. This will be the strongest upgrade path until you get lightning available.

Reinforced Club:
Raw+5 is 224
Mag+5 is 146+158 = 304
Mag+9 is 175+189 = 364

Also, raw is unbuffable so a Normal+10 is 194 + Gold Pine Resin (150) = 344 which is better for bosses.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have both a lightning +5 and Chaos +5 Battleaxe for my SL1 character the lightning one is 450 damage and the chaos is 495 not bad damage for an SL1

Answer (score 0):

Chaos Reinforced Club +5 with 10 Humanity (soft) has an AR of 505.
Blacksmith Giant Hammer has an AR of 500, but requires two handing.
Lightning Reinforced Club +5 has an AR of 484.

For PvP however, I would say the best SL1 weapon would be a Jagged Ghost Blade. Its two handed R1 is extremely fast and can cause blood loss. I would also recommend a Magic Reinforced Club +10 over lightning or chaos in PvP because most shields and armor used in PvP have relatively poor protection against magic damage.

Good luck out there.